# At which line is the copy constructor called?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a few lines of code and I don't get, why and where the copy constructor is called. Could you explain it to me?

The output is:

> CS10
>
> CS99
>
> CC100
>
> Obj10=Obj100
>
> D100
>
> Obj10=Obj99
>
> D99
>
> D10

This is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class my
{
    int m;
public:
    my(int i): m(i)
    {
        cout << "CS" << m << endl;
    }
    my(const my& c): m(c.m+1)
    {
        cout << "CC" << m << endl;
    }
    ~my()
    {
        cout << "D" << m << endl;
    }
    my& operator=(const my &c)
    {
        cout << "Obj" << m << "=Obj" << c.m << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

my f(my* x)
{
    return *x;
}

int main()
{
    my m1(10);
    my m2(99);

    m1 = f(&m2); // creates a new object
    m1 = m2;     // does not create a new object
}
```

Why and where is copy constructor called causing the output CC100 and D100?

Comment: When returning `my` by value from a function.

Comment: Ah... Sure... I didn't notice that it was copied... The *x confused me a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function

```
my f(my* x)
{
    return *x;
}
```

called in statement

```
m1 = f(&m2); // creates a new object
```

the copy constructor is called to copy object *x in the return temporary object.

In fact it looks as

```
my tmp = *x; // the copy constructor is called
m1 = tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that it is returned by value. I thought it was returned by reference and didn't notice it was dereferenced. :/ Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to think about when a copy constructor is called you should keep a few things in mind:

1. Scope - functions can't see outside of themselves and their associated namespace. If you want to pass a variable to a function you need to save it in the global environment, repush a scoped copy and then operate on it.
2. When you use passing by reference you operate on the global copy but since in this case you are returning the value that is pointed to and not a pointer you have to push that return value onto the stack separately because it is stored at a different temporary register address that is popped off the stack after you assign it to a permanent location in main. That's where the destructor comes in.
3. You made a temporary return value to pass the value out of your function so it's got to be deleted because L1, L2, and L3 cache are all prime real estate.

I highly recommend doing a little bit of reading on assembly code operations or even try compiling simple programs into assembly and seeing how the low level languages work under the hood. Cheers!